# XLWT: How to access previously written cells?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwt

I have created a excel workbook using 'xlwt'.In my program, which is given below, I write few cells some values. Now, how do i access those cells?

```
    """ Create 'Data_Table.xls' Excel workbook """
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Data_Table")

""" Define First row in 'Data_Table.xls'"""
sheet1.write(0,0, "Variable Name")
sheet1.write(0,1, "Global Static Variable?")
```

How do i access data in cell (0, 0) or (0, 1)?

Comment: Have a look at [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to open the File with e.g. XLRD-Library. I think that this is the only way to get the data of the written file.

Greetings,
Frame